# How to copy to PC?

Tags: droid-explorer

I downloaded Droid Explorer correctly, Busy Box and can view my files (on my Android device) .. but when I select the file to copy how can I drop it on to my PC drive?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to accomplish this.

You select the files (folders are currently not supported) and click the "copy to PC" toolbar button.

[image]

The other is to select the files (folders are currently not supported) and right click and click "copy". Then paste the files to your desired location.

[image]

There are plans to attempt to allow for dragging and dropping, but I do not have a timeline.

---

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of Droid Explorer*